# Hiding and showing a javafx stage without losing data

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

So I wasn't able to find a topic on this, but it is possible to somehow make a JavaFX stage invisible, but not close / hide the stage.

For instance:

```
stage.hide()
```

Will essentially close the stage, making it so that if you want to use:

```
stage.show()
```

You'd have to reconstruct the entire stage.

To rephrase:

"Is it possible to make a JavaFX stage invisible and then visible again without losing any data?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I came across this topic:

[JavaFX: can you create a stage that doesn't show on the task bar and is undecorated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564136/javafx-can-you-create-a-stage-that-doesnt-show-on-the-task-bar-and-is-undecora)

And as it turns out using:

```
// Note that this is Kotlin
stage.opacity = 0.0
stage.opacity = 1.0
```

Will make the stage not visible, but retain its information.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep a reference to the stage's controller, you can close it and make a new stage using the same controller which has all the same information in it.